# Jackson - there is a key of @class and its value is the class full path - any reason for this?

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following `MediaPlayerState` class, and I obtained its instance as an `Object` type. I serialized this class instance and the returned `stateString` has a key of `@class` which points to its class path.

My question is what is this `@class` used for? Can it be used to correctly deserialzie the `stateString` to correct class type without supplying `MediaPlayerState.class` as in Try 1?

```
Class MediaPlayerState() {
    private String client;
    private String playbackState;
}

// Jackson Serialize
Object value = method.invoke(this, null); // this returned MediaPlayerState
map.put(key, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value));

stateString = {"@class":"com.jessica.mediaplayer.MediaPlayerState",
               "playbackState":null,
               "client":null}

// Jackson Deserialize try 1 -- able to get correct MediaPlayerState
MediaPlayerState state = objectMapper.readValue(stateString, MediaPlayerState.class);

// Jackson Deserialize try 2 -- incorrect
Object state = objectMapper.readValue(stateString, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there are two ObjectMapper.

1. jackson-mapper: `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`;
2. jackson-databind: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

For the case in the question, I used ObjectMapper of 2. If I use 1st one, I am able to get rid of `@class` in the serialized String.